# How do I create a Virus signature?

Tags: c, signature, antivirus, virus

How can I create my own virus signature of a .exe or .lib file? I started my reading certain bytes to the file and then just storing them in another file and manually adding this to a virus scanner. Will this work? thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make a file you can simply load into an existing free or commercial AV product? If so, you should specify which one...

Comment: 67% isn't necessarily all that low. My rate is probably somewhere around that, and it's because I've asked a lot of hard questions that still have very incomplete answers or no correct answers at all.

Comment: are you looking for [EICAR test file](http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to create a signature of a file, one of the simplest, and easiest, is to take a hashing function, like SHA1, and run it against the whole file.

Comment: Considering even the childish [polymorphic viruses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code) from 15 or 20 years ago can easily walk right past an SHA1 or similar hashing mechanism, these sorts of hashes aren't a good tool for virus scanning.

Comment: I am not trying to prevent virus, I want to create a test program that creates virus definition files so that certain files are quarantined on purpose

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to find a sequence of bytes that's makes it unique, the AV companies spend a lot of time to analyse the behaviour, traints and find something unique. And the Antivirus application reads the binary file to look for the byte pattern

Kindly read the [Antivirus fundamentals: Viruses, signatures, disinfection](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/signature-virus-disinfection/13233/) from Kasperskey

To start with basic you need to create/maintain a hex table where signature is unique column followed by the Name, Type. And read files in your computer and try to get a match with the Hex database table.

Now how to keep it unique, as it's hard to analyse each `.exe` on your own to get the signature. As stated here, kindly read the [intro-to-creating-anti-virus-signatures](http://hooked-on-mnemonics.blogspot.com/2011/01/intro-to-creating-anti-virus-signatures.html?m=1)

Look for what is `yara` Engine & Rules here [virustotal.github.io/yara/](http://virustotal.github.io/yara/) and how **VirusTotal** uses it to create AV signatures then on to rules [yararules.com](https://yararules.com/) .There are few tools like [yaraeditor](https://www.adlice.com/download/yaraeditor/) to help you out but with google you can find more.

Then you can put your hands on OpenSource Antivirus like **ClamAV** [github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav-devel](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav-devel) and use it for purpose.